# magento checkout change TAX to VAT

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I am using default Magento checkout and would like to change the checkout final step from `TAX` to `VAT`.

- **Subtotal**                                : €9.38
- **Shipping & Handling** (Flat Rate - Fixed) : €6.50
- **Tax**                                     : €2.16
- **Grand Total**                             : €18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by going into you Magento Admin. From there go `Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules`. Then rename the name of your Tax Rules from "*Tax*" to "*VAT*"

You may need to may additional changes in your Templates. But this sufficed for me!

Comment: there is just option Manage Tax Rules or Manage Tax Zone and Rates. No other option to change.

Comment: That sounds like you don't have any Tax Rules in place. It might just be easier to change the references to __('Tax') to VAT in the template