# Change Tax text to VAT

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, tax

I have already looked at the following post 
[magento checkout change TAX to VAT](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/magento-checkout-change-tax-to-vat)
I've done this part: 
You can change this by going into you Magento Admin. From there go Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules. Then rename the name of your Tax Rules from "Tax" to "VAT"

I've also done a Search in All the Themes in app\design\frontend\ For 'TAX' _('TAX') and every conceivable search for TAX and manged to change the following URL /checkout/cart/:

BASKET TOTALS

Total Excl. VAT £83.33

**Tax   £16.67**

Total Incl. VAT £100.00

The part in bold I can't seem to alter no matter what I can't find where to change it???

in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\grandtotal.phtml

line 40 is this bit of code

```
    <?php echo $this->renderTotals('taxes', $this->getColspan()); ?>
```

This is the part what displays it, but not sure which file, database table it is pulling from, If anyone knows it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Resolved Turns out on line 78 of app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\tax.phtml

 <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
        <?php endif;?>

I just commented out the echo.... and replaced with VAT

This might NOT be the correct way, but at least everything says VAT and NOT Tax

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just need to update all things in CSV translation file. If you are in UK, you can use en_GB language package. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved Turns out on line 78 of app\design\frontend\base\default\template\tax\checkout\tax.phtml

```
  <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

I just commented out the echo part.... and replaced with VAT

This might NOT be the correct way, but at least everything says VAT and NOT Tax