# how to add extra fee for international order in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not developer, I am  Web/Graphics designer.  only I am handle whole multi designer website. when some one place order from out of india, add extra charge per product price or destination.

Answer (score 2):

you can use table rate shipping method for this feature.....

While logged in as admin, navigate to **System > Configuration** and then, in the left menu under **Sales**, select **Shipping Methods**. than you can enter Shipping prices and country name in excel sheet as below :

[image]

please check below links for more information  :

https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_shipping_rates.htm

http://creatingawebstore.com/how-to-setup-table-rates-shipping-in-magento.html

Comment: One More issue, i create GST Rule. it's working fine. but when someone placed order, i want to change word 'Tax' into 'GST' . can you help how will change.

Comment: @AtulKumar you can do that by following these links [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/magento-checkout-change-tax-to-vat) , [link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154885/change-tax-text-to-vat) , [link3](http://navaneeth.me/change-tax-vat-magento/#.WYf0R4R97IU) , [link4](https://ankursphp.blogspot.in/2014/09/how-to-change-text-tax-to-vat-in.html)

Comment: @AtulKumar please accept this answer.....

Comment: @AtulKumar Say something to Baby in Magento, Atul Kumar...